# Why can't I convert Vector<Vector<Number>> to AbstractList<AbstractList<Number>> in Java?

Tags: java, generics, vector

Why does

```
AbstractList<AbstractList<Number>> list = new Vector<Vector<Number>();
```

generates the following error :

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Vector<Vector<Number>> to AbstractList<AbstractList<Number>>
```

whereas Vector extends AbstractList?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate, but while I find it - consider what operations you can perform on an `AbstractList<AbstractList<Number>>`. You can perform `add(new ArrayList<Number>())` for example. You can't do that to a `Vector<Vector<Number>>`.

Comment: `Vector<Vector<Number>> a = new Vector<Vector<Number>>(); AbstractList<AbstractList<Number>> b = a; b.add(new LinkedList<Number>()); Vector<Number> c = a.get(0); // ????`

Answer (score 2):

When using Java generics, you have to use `? extends AbstractList`:

```
AbstractList<? extends AbstractList<Number>> list = new Vector<Vector<Number>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were able to do that, it would mean that you can call `list.add(someAbstractList)` which would be wrong because of the actual type of `list`: it is expecting a `Vector` (or a class that extends it) and not some other implementation of `AbstractList`.